# Convert docx to pdf - Free

Tags: c#, pdf, converters, docx

I have seen many questions on this but still couldn't find my answer.

I want to be able to convert a `docx` file to a `pdf` file without having word installed. Is there maybe a free library out there? I really don't want to pay for this.
I read a post about `XSL-FO` and i found a `XSL-FO` to pdf converter library, not sure if that works.

So without using of`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` I want to convert `docx` to `pdf`

Comment: This is a solution but i would prefer not to install anything on the server.

Comment: have you considered to import the docx file into libre/openoffice and export it to pdf thereafter ?

Comment: [these guys](http://www.e-iceblue.com) claim to ship a standalone .net class named [spire.doc](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-for-net-introduce.html) to do the trick, selling for 600-800 $. disclaimer: i am not affiliated with this company nor do i use their product, i just stumbled upon them searching for a similar tool you have in mind.

Comment: yeah, i saw them too, but its kind of a heavy fee to pay.